# Hand-built JSON vs JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

### Background

I have a bunch of objects that need their state to be sent to the server in json representation. It currently works something like this:

```
MyClass.prototype.GetJSON(){
    return '{"title":"' + m_Title + '","description":"' + m_Desc + '"}'; 

};
```

### Problem

The guy that I work with is suggesting that I do something like this instead:

```
MyClass.prototype.GetJSON(){
    return JSON.stringify( {title:m_Title, description:m_Desc} ); 

};
```

What are the pros/cons of doing something like this? Is it more/less efficient than what I'm already doing?

Comment: good lord, why would you do by hand what most javascript engines give you for free?

Answer (score 5):

What if m_Title has JS metachars in it?

```
m_Title = 'John "Beast" Johnson';
```

producing

```
{"title":"John "Beast" Johnson", ...}
                ^^^^^--oops
```

nice syntax error. Sorry for the powerplant meltdown your code just caused.

Never build JSON by hand when your host language has facilities to do it for you.

This is exactly the same as an SQL injection problem - failing to take into account the environment your inserted text is being used in, and blindly assuming nothing could ever possibly go wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Advantages of using a JSON library over string mashing:

- The code is clearer: Easier to read, easier to debug, easier to understand the *purpose* of the code
- It takes an (unlikely) bug in the library to generate invalid JSON

Advantages of using string mashing:

There aren't any.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.stringify`.

It's

- more standard
- easier to read : no need to check what does the code
- sure to escape what needs to be escaped

Keeping your existing code will bring you surprises the day you'll have quotes in you strings or the day you'll try to extend your current application logic to other types.

If it's important to you to support IE7, you should take into account that you need a library (see [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=json)).

Comment: Don't forget to mention that IE7 does not natively support the JSON object.

Answer (score 0):

It will be slightly less efficient, but more standardized.  Plus, using `stringify` will prevent things like injection...